# Find end of paragraph with regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

How do I find the end of a paragraph (where user in TextBox type ENTER)? What is the right regex to do it? I am using this code:

```
    Protected Function MakeParagraph(ByVal txt As String) As String
    Dim regx As New Regex("/n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)        
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = regx.Matches(txt)

    For Each Match As Match In matches
        txt = txt.Replace(Match.Value, "<br/>")
    Next        
    Return txt
End Function

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = MakeParagraph(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no need to use a Regex here: Just replace all line breaks with `<br/>`:

```
Protected Function MakeParagraph(ByVal txt As String) As String
    Return txt.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br/>")
End Function
```

And, by the way, if you want to create HTML (it looks like you want to do that), don't forget to [HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) the text before replacing line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use Regex?
Couldn't you just do something like:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(vbNewLine, "</br>")
End Sub
```

Also, you can split each paragraph and work on them in this way:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim Paragraphs() as String = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
    For Each Paragraph in Paragraphs
        'Do something with the paragraph ex:
        'Label1.Text &= Paragraph & "</br>"
    Next        
End Sub
```